# How to return more than 1 of the same values in each row

Tags: python, dataframe, list, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I have a data frame with the same values in some of the rows. I would like to return the row number and values that has more than 1 of the same value starting from Num1 to Num7 in df.
Also would like to return the row number and same value. Either or I'm okay with.

## For example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,2,4,5,6,7,7],
            [2,5,6,7,22,23,34,48],
            [3,3,5,6,7,45,46,48],
            [4,6,7,14,29,32,6,29], # duplicate 6 and 29
            [5,6,7,13,23,33,35,7], # duplicate 7 but nothing else
            [6,1,6,7,8,9,10,8],
            [7,0,2,5,7,19,7,5]], # duplicate 7,5 
            columns = ['Row_Num', 'Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6','Num7'])
```

## First result

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[4,6,7,14,29,32], # Return 6 and 29
                   [7,0,2,5,7,19]], # Return 7,5 
            columns = ['Row_Num', 'Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5'])
```

## Second result

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[4,6,29], # Return 6 and 29
                   [7,7,5]], # Return 7,5 
            columns = ['Row_Num', 'Num1','Num2'])
```

Comment: Your question is a little difficult to understand, are you trying to return which of the values in df2/df3 are duplicates in a row in df?

Comment: No in df . Df2 and the df3 is the result im looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use [pd.duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with a some data manipulation to get your result:

```
df = df.set_index('Row_Num') # set index
df_duplicated = df.transform(lambda x: x.duplicated(), axis=1) # returns if rows have duplicates

# First result where 
res1 = df[df_duplicated.sum(axis=1) >= 2][~df_duplicated[df_duplicated.sum(axis=1) >= 2]].dropna(axis=1)

# second result
res2 = df[df_duplicated.sum(axis=1) >= 2][df_duplicated[df_duplicated.sum(axis=1) >= 2]].dropna(axis=1)
```

Output:

`result1`

```
         Num1  Num2  Num3  Num4  Num5
Row_Num                              
4           6     7    14    29    32
7           0     2     5     7    19
```

`result2`:

```
         Num6  Num7
Row_Num            
4           6    29
7           7     5
```

To exactly match your output just `reset_index` and rename column names for the second result.